# Issue with Objects in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having issues searching in an array of objects. Basically what my page needs to do is to create a new "client" using information entered by me, such as Full name, User name, Email and Password. Each one of these clients are objects in an array as you can see below.

```
var clientlist = [{"username":"John","fullname":"John Doe",
"email":"john.doe@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"jdoe2"},
```

This client is already created in my js file, what I need to do is to create a new object to add to this array with this same structure. For example,

```
var clientlist = [{"username":"Peter","fullname":"Peter Jones",
"email":"peter.jones@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"pjones1"},
```

I have written the code but it doesn't work properly, when I run the Firebug I can see that all elements have been added correctly except for the Username which value is "". I cannot seem to search for the username to see if the username that I am adding already exists, it may be a syntax mistake. I will leave my complete code below and thanks in advance for the assistance!.

```
var clientlist = [{"username":"John","fullname":"John Doe",
"email":"john.doe@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"jdoe2"},

var Client = {};

function NewClient(){
var found;
var user = $("#username").val();

for (var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) {
    if (clientlist[i].username == user) {
        found = true;
    }else{
        found = false;
    }
}

if (found == true){
    $("#msj").html("User already exists!");
}
else if(found == false){
    Client["fullname"] = $("#fullname").val();
    Client["username"] = user;
    Client["email"] = $("#email").val();
    Client["type"] = "client";
    Client["password"] = $("#password").val();

    clientlist[clientlist.length] = Client;

    $("#msj").html("New client has been created");
}
```

}

Comment: you have missing `]` at the end of `clientlist` value. `var clientlist = [{"username":"John","fullname":"John Doe",
"email":"john.doe@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"jdoe2"}]`

Comment: you ignored using `break` in the loop from solution I gave you yesterday. Or setting `found=false` and remove `else`

Comment: `var Client = {};` needs to be inside the `NewClient()` function.

Comment: what you need is `{username: Object}`, then use `in` to test duplicate.

Comment: @hendrix Please don't edit your question to fix issues that people have mentioned in the answers. This is very confusing for other people reading this thread.

Comment: Guys the missing `]` is only because it is a larger file that I extracted this in order to simplify, ignore that. I have added the suggestions you gave me yesterday charlietfl, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few mistakes that you made:

- Forgot to close the `clientlist` array
- Forgot to actually push the newly added client

This code below should work correcting a few mistakes that you made along the way.

```
var clientlist = [{
  "username": "John",
  "fullname": "John Doe",
  "email": "john.doe@hotmail.com",
  "type": "client",
  "password": "jdoe2"
}];

function NewClient() {
  var found = false;
  var user = $("#username").val();

  for (var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) {
    if (clientlist[i].username == user) {
      found = true;
    } else {
      found = false;
    }
  }

  if (found) {
    $("#msj").html("User already exists!");
  } else {
    var newUser = {
      fullname: $("#fullname").val(),
      username: user,
      email: $("#email").val(),
      type: "client",
      password: $("#password").val()
    }
    clientlist.push(newUser);
    $("#msj").html("New client has been created");
  }
}
```

Made a fiddle for you:
http://codepen.io/gabrielgodoy/pen/xOxoWw?editors=1011

Comment: I tried this but when I check the object with Firebug username is still "", instead of being John for example, any ideas?

Comment: @hendrix, check if you actually have a `#username` element in your HTML. I updated the Codepen with a console.log for you to see that the username there is being filled. 

Here: http://codepen.io/gabrielgodoy/pen/xOxoWw?editors=1011

Comment: Yes I do have the #username, this is so frustrating because my code now looks exactly like the one you showed me in fiddle with the slight difference that mine doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have several issues.

1. Ending bracket of the clientList
2. For loop and the found variable
3. pushing new user to the client list.

I have corrected them and included it below.

```
<script>
var clientlist = [{"username":"John","fullname":"John Doe",
"email":"john.doe@hotmail.com","type":"client","password":"jdoe2"}]

function NewClient(){
    var found=false;
    var user = $("#username").val();

    for (var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) {
        if (clientlist[i].username==user) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found){
        $("#msj").html("User already exists!");
    }
    else{
        var newUser={
            fullname:$("#fullname").val(),
            username:user,
            email:$("#email").val(),
            type:"client",
            password:$("#password").val()
        }

        clientlist.push(newUser);
        $("#msj").html("New client has been created");
    }
}
</script>
```